# Mesmo código produzindo resultados distintos no Codeenvy e Windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, csv

Eu tinha feito o seguinte código no codevy.io e o Python instalado no codenvy é o 3.5.1. Peguei esse código e botei para rodar no windows 8 com python 3.6.1.

O propósito do código é limpar uns arquivos CSV e escreve-los concatenados em um só arquivo CSV.No codenvy está funcionando, mas ao executar o código no windows o arquivo de saí fica com linhas em branco entre cada row,quero saber como contornar isso:

```
import csv
import sys
import os
import glob

interesting_files = glob.glob("Vendas_artigos*")

with open('SaidaVendasArtigos.csv','wt',encoding='utf-8-sig') as fout:
    for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
        with open(filename,'rt',encoding='utf-8-sig') as fin:
            next(fin)
            reader = csv.reader(fin)
            writer = csv.writer(fout)
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    row.pop(0)
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Python 3.5.1 no Codenvy:

```
row
row
row
```

Python 3.6.1 no Windows 8:

```
row

row

row
```

Comment: Primeiro, comece fazendo o [tour] pelo site para entender como o mesmo funciona. Nele encontrará vários materiais de como perguntar, incluindo sobre formatação de perguntas e respostas. Segundo, tente adicionar um nível de indentação à última linha `writer.writerow(row)`, fazendo com que seja escrito apenas se a linha não estiver vazia.

Comment: Ah sim,desculpe,vou fazer o tour pra já.Bom, o nível de identação na ultima linha não funcionou,tho.

Comment: O resultado foi o mesmo?

Comment: Desculpe a demora,Foi o mesmo resultado,Anderson.

Answer (score 1):

Posso estar enganado, mas pode ser que no momento que usa `writerow` a variável `row` já tenha quebra de linha, então poderia usar `.strip` assim:

```
reader = csv.reader(fin)
writer = csv.writer(fout)
for row in reader:
    if row:
        row.pop(0)
    writer.writerow(row.strip('\r\n'))
```

No argumento de `strip`, usei `\r` e `\n` para que remova apenas as quebras de linha (*line feed (LF)*) e *carriage return (CR)*

Algo que me deixou curioso foi o uso de `row.pop(0)`, creio que isto vai remover sempre o primeiro item do index, afetando o comportamento do `for` o que parece que pode causar bastante confusão no `for` mesmo, eu mesmo não entendi a necessidade de manipular o vetor se você esta apenas copiado os dados para um novo arquivo, creio que talvez você queria fazer algo como isto:

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Ou:

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        writer.writerow(row.strip('\r\n'))
```

E o `reader` se realmente deseja "manipular" para uso posterior, você poderia manipular com `pop` antes ou depois em outro `for`

Comment: Bem reparado em relação ao `pop`; eu não havia notado.

Comment: Então Guilherme, o:
         for row in reader:
         if row:
            row.pop(0)
            writer.writerow(row.strip('\r\n'))

gerou um arquivo em branco. O 'row.pop(0)' é porque precisava deletar a primeira coluna de cada arquivo CSV que eu estou abrindo para escrever na saida, que concatena todos os outros arquivos "limpos",entende?

O que eu fiz que resolveu,usar a luz que tu focou no método "writerow" e la eu vi que poderia colocar o parâmetro ", newline='' ", que resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Merda,os comentários só podem ser editados em 5 minutos :X ficou uma bagunça minha resposta.Desculpem.